# Enable PHP8.1 extension PCNTL on Ubuntu 22.04 and Docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, pcntl

I am trying to enable the PCNTL extension for PHP 8.1 on Ubuntu 22.04 but have been unsuccessful.

When I run a command `php -i | grep pcntl` via terminal it returns `pcntl support => enabled` but the php function `extension_loaded('pcntl')` returns `false`

Is there some CLI command which can enable the extension directly?